# C++ Не работает AnsiString (индификатор AnsiString не определён)

Tags: c++, ansi

Вот такой код:

```
AnsiString path = "BrowserBot.exe";
ShellExecute(0, TEXT("open"), path.c_str(), TEXT("-параментры"), 0, SW_SHOW); //запускаем
```

Пишет ошибку что индификатор AnsiString не определён. Не знаю в чём проблема

Всё подключенные библиотеки:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
```

Помогите разобраться

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, насколько мне удалось узнать, это типы из Borland C++ Builder, так что без него это работать не будет.
Во-вторых, [вот здесь](http://cbuilder.ru/index.php?topic=5483.0) советуют сделать так (в добавок к Вашим директивам):

```cpp
#include <Classes.hpp>
#include <Controls.hpp>
#include <StdCtrls.hpp>
```